# ckeditor source view changes html code when switching view

Tags: ckeditor

My html code gets changed when i switched from design to source view.
I pasted the following code

```
<div>test</div>
```

But when ichanged to design view and then cme again to source view code changed.
Below is the changed code

```
<p>test</p>
```

Why the div changed to p
Please help me how to fix this..

Comment: What does your CKEditor config look like?

Comment: Below is my config setting

config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

 // Se the most common block elements.
 config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

 // Make dialogs simpler.
 config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
 config.extraPlugins = 'strinsert';
 config.startupMode = 'source';
 config.removePlugins = 'help';
 config.extraPlugins = 'stylesheetparser';
 config.contentsCss = 'test.css';

Comment: Is there any setting in config..?
Please suggest
thanks

Comment: I was asking because I wanted to reproduce the problem but I couldn't. I couldn't reproduce your enviroment 100% either, but I made this: http://jsfiddle.net/h3yeH/ - in there it works just fine. Now my suspicion goes to two things: What version of CKEditor are you using and how do you set the data for it? Do you use `setData()` Or do you do it like I did in that jsfiddle?

Comment: I am using 4.2 version of ckeditor
I am just calling ckeditor by following code in ready function
 $('textarea').ckeditor();
because i have multiple textareas are there in my page

Comment: And how do you set the data for CKEditor? Do you load it from a database and place it directly in the HTML during page load, like I did in jsfiddle or do you do it dynamically somehow using `setData()`? Does the data within the normal non-CKEDITOR textarea look good, meaning that it might be a htmlencoding issue. I first thought it might be an AdvancedContentFilter issue, but if that's your config i doubt it. Still, I strongly recommend trying to set `config.allowedContent = true;` just to be sure, try that. Do you have a link you could give where I could see the problem?

Comment: config.allowedContent = true;
seems working 
Thanks alot for your answers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was resolved in the comments section.

Advanced Content Filtering (ACF) was preventing DIV elements from entering into the content, it was transforming them into P elements. Setting `config.allowedContent = true;` solved the issue.

If the ACF should remain turned on to filter other unwanted data, another option would have been to set `config.extraAllowedContent = 'div';`. This way the ACF still works, but also allows DIV elements.

For more on ACF check out http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter

Comment: I have my html tags like:

`<div class='travel_box'><a class='travel_box_link' href='/flights/cheap-flights-to-paris'><img src='//t.x-bit.us/images/portal/9/hexa-images/paris.jpg' alt ='Paris Flights'/><h3>Paris</h3><p>BOOK NOW</p></a></div>`

Comment: But ckeditor change html code like :
`<div class="travel_box">
<a class="travel_box_link" href="/flights/cheap-flights-to-london">
<img alt="London" src="//t.x-bit.us/images/portal/9/hexa-images/london.jpg" />
</a>
<h3>
<a class="travel_box_link" href="/flights/cheap-flights-to-london">London</a>
</h3>
<a class="travel_box_link" href="/flights/cheap-flights-to-london">
</a>

<p><a class="travel_box_link" href="/flights/cheap-flights-to-london">BOOK NOW</a></p>
<a class="travel_box_link" href="/flights/cheap-flights-to-london"> </a></div>`

Comment: I have added allowedContent true but it won't works please help

Comment: @shiva Sounds like it's not working or your situation is somehow different - please ask a separate question about that, the comment section is too small to really diagnose properly :)

Answer (score 0):

Open `Config.js`, add this line before the closing curly brace (`}`):

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.extraAllowedContent = 'div';
```