# CKEDITOR changes original HTML (when switching between source and WYSIWYG)

Tags: ckeditor

Whenever I switch between source code view and WYSIWYG the CKEDITOR HTML source code changes.

I would like it didn't.

For example: I switch to source code, set **Hi** as the source code and when I switch to WYSIWYG, the CKEDITOR wraps the **Hi** with a *p* tag.

I already tried

```
 config.allowedContent = true;
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641501/ckeditor-source-view-changes-html-code-when-switching-view) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386864/ckeditor4-destroy-not-preserve-original-html-content-how-to-disable-filters) and the *p* still is being added.

Is there a way of making CKEDITOR leave HTML source code untouched?

Comment: Yea, use a regular textarea. What's the point of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor automatically wraps inline content in paragraphs and this feature is called auto paragraphing. It is very important for the content to be clean and editable. So I highly recommend accepting the default behaviour. CKEditor really knows what it must do.

However, if you cannot accept this for some reason, then use [`config.autoParagraph`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-autoParagraph) option. But note that this option is **deprecated**.